# difference among NSthread and NStimer and NSNotifcation?

Tags: iphone

What is the difference among following codes

1)

```
 [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(myFunction) toTarget:self withObject:thename];
```

2)

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                 target:self 
                               selector:@selector(myFunction:) 
                               userInfo:nil 
                                repeats:NO];
```

3)

```
[self performSelector:@selector(myFunction) withObject:nil afterDelay:myDelay];
```

4)

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(myFunction:) name:thename object:nil];
```

Answer (score 5):

1. Performs selector in a separate thread. You need to set up your own autorelease pool if you want to autorelease objects in the called function. You cannot directly work with GUI but you won’t block it if the function takes too long to finish. Probably better written using `performSelectorInBackground:` of `NSObject`.
2. Runs selector after delay on the main thread. No need for an autorelease pool (you’re using the default one), you can work with GUI directly but you will block it if the function takes too long to finish.
3. Very much like 2.
4. Something completely different, see the documentation for [NSNotificationCenter](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html). You tell the default notification center that you want to receive all notification of name `thename` sent by `nil` (= any object). When such notification is posted, the notification center will call `myFunction` and pass it an instance of `NSNotification` that describes the event.

I hope I got everything right, the first three points are a bit tricky.

Comment: u said performSelectorInBackground is better because of from NSObject.but detachNewThreadSelector (NSThread.h) which is also derived from NSObject.the doc (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539460/what-is-the-difference-between-nsthread-detachnewthreadselectortotargetwithob/6883442#6883442)says the both are same.then difference is only autorelease pool. performSelectorInBackground is create automatically pool.but detach.. not.am i right?is there any reason to u prefered for background method.please guide me.